# VLC module not playing song while in if statement

Tags: python, vlc

I tried to write code that asks the user what song that user wants to play (among a shown list of choices), but the problem is that the vlc module doesn't want to play the song. However, I've tried it without the if statement and it works. It's my first time coding so I'm sorry if the code looks messed up:

```
from tinytag import TinyTag as chimera
import vlc

def choice():
    try:
        print('music1')
        print('music2')
        print('music3')
        music = int(input('choose the song you like\n'))
        info(music)
        musical(music)
    except ValueError:
        choice()

def info(music):
    try:
        if music == 1:
            tag = chimera.get('C:/Users/user/music/music1.ogg')
            print('song name %s' % tag.title )
            print('Duration %f' % tag.duration)
        elif music == 2:
            tag = chimera.get('C:/Users/user/music/music2.m4a')
            print('song name %s' % tag.title)
            print('Duration %f' % tag.duration)
        elif music == 3:
            tag = chimera.get('C:/Users/user/music3.m4a')
            print('song name %s' % tag.title)
            print('Duration %f' % tag.duration)
        else:
            print('invalid input')
            choice()
    except SyntaxError:
      pass

def musical(music):
    playing = input('do you want to play the music?\n')
    if music == 1 and playing == 'yes':
        player1 = vlc.MediaPlayer('C:/Users/user/music/music1.ogg')
        player1.play()
    elif music == 2 and playing == 'yes':
        player2 = vlc.MediaPlayer('C:/Users/user/music/music2.m4a')
        player2.play()
    elif music == 3 and playing == 'yes':
        player3 = vlc.MediaPlayer('C:/Users/user/music/music3.m4a')
        player3.play()
choice()
```

Comment: Note: `try: except SyntaxError:`? Better try writing syntactically correct code instead. Also, you could simplify your functions by using `'C:/Users/user/music/music%s.ogg' % music`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the program running while `vlc` is active.
I've amended your code a bit and for my purposes, I've dropped the `tinytag` references.

```
import vlc
import time

def choice():
    try:
        print('music1')
        print('music2')
        print('music3')
        music = int(input('choose the song you like( 1-3 )\n'))
        if music < 1 or music > 3:
            raise ValueError
        musical(music)
    except ValueError:
        print("Input error\n")
        choice()

def musical(music):
    if music == 1:
        player = vlc.MediaPlayer('C:/Users/user/music/music1.ogg')
    elif music == 2:
        player = vlc.MediaPlayer('C:/Users/user/music/music2.ogg')
    elif music == 3:
        player = vlc.MediaPlayer('C:/Users/user/music/music3.ogg')
    player.play()
    playing = set([1,2,3,4])
    time.sleep(0.1)
    while True:
        state = player.get_state()
        if state not in playing:
            break
        time.sleep(1)

choice()
```

Note that the vlc player `state` values are:

```
0: 'NothingSpecial',
1: 'Opening',
2: 'Buffering',
3: 'Playing',
4: 'Paused',
5: 'Stopped',
6: 'Ended',
7: 'Error',
```